# Webserver crash due to lt-httpd segfault error 6

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, segmentation-fault

We have webserver hosting wordpress website on a debian machine. Two days ago, it suddenly crashed and started to log the following errors in `/var/log/messages`. However, there are no entries in the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/apache2/access.log`

```
Jan  9 09:55:05 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21834]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:56:13 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21824]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:56:36 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21827]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:57:31 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21840]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:57:33 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21841]: segfault at 00007fff3544afb8 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544afc0 error 6
Jan  9 09:57:40 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21844]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:57:53 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21846]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:58:02 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21847]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:58:03 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21848]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:58:04 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21838]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:58:05 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21855]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:58:27 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21859]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:58:28 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21861]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:58:29 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21862]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:58:30 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21865]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:59:35 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21866]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:59:36 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21867]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 09:59:37 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21857]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 10:00:17 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21871]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 10:00:18 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21873]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 10:00:19 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21874]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
Jan  9 10:00:19 server-name kernel: lt-httpd[21877]: segfault at 00007fff3544af28 rip 00002b4475e212f5 rsp 00007fff3544af30 error 6
```

I started to work on this server two days ago and do not have a in depth knowledge of it. Whenever we try to hit the website it hosts, it logs a new line of segfault. If any one could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

The server has:

```
PHP v5.2.5
Apache v2.2.3
```

Comment: The error code of 6 on the end means that the segfault was caused by a user-mode write resulting in no page being found.

Comment: What log is this in? Kernel message makes me think it was syslog.

Comment: @BrokenBinary I found that information as well but don't know what it really means. The server was working fine two days ago and we didin't change a single thing.

Comment: @LuckyBurger it is in the `syslog`

Comment: Can you create a page (phpinfo.php): <?php phpinfo(); ?> then do a wget, wget localhost/phpinfo.php

Comment: @LuckyBurger it is done, what should I look for?

Comment: Well if its a server problem the wget should be empty. if it actually has stuff in it then im even more perplexed. if it is NOT empty please post its contents, it could be useful to see what PHP is loaded with.

Comment: @LuckyBurger you can access the contents of it through this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhwuoe3ydxuzhfd/phpinfo.html?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68519/discussion-between-luckyburger-and-brkk).

Comment: @LuckyBurger Lucky, I have couple quick questions about wordpress, wondering if you could help me with that.

Comment: Sure, just attach them here.

Comment: @LuckyBurger Thank you for your time, but I have managed to solve my problem. I was having problems accessing admin pages after upgrading the wordpress version, but I on my second try things went on smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be caused by a plug-in named  "Wiki Lite". Our page was using the version 1.0.8.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem comes from a bad configuration in PHP
Have you "apc.so" enabled in your "php.ini" ? if yes disable it and restart apache server

Comment: There is no reference `apc.so` in the `php.ini` file.

Comment: It turned out to be a plug-in problem.